# Spring rest application and exception localization

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I am developing a spring boot app with restful services and angularjs as front end. The application must support multiple languages. One of the things I am having problem is the business exceptions thrown from my services. E.g. I have a book service which may throw an exception like this

```
if (book == null) {
        throw new ServiceException("The book you are looking for no longer exist");
}
```

What is the best approach to localize them?

Comment: Show some code. What exactly you are trying to achieve. Front end localized message? or exception localization.?

Comment: yes, I am talking about exception localization. I have modified the question a bit.

Comment: You can throw an exception with a code that you translate into a friendly message in the controller layer. (by injecting `MessageSource`). See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource

Comment: Are you looking for [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **@RestControllerAdvice** to seprate your exception handling logic from your business code. As per @ControllerAdvice doc, the methods defined in the class annotated as @ControllerAdvice  apply globally to all Controllers. @RestControllerAdvice is just a convenience class equal to **(@RestControllerAdvice = @ControllerAdvice + @ResponseBody)**. Please check below class:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(ServiceException.class e, Locale locale) {

            String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(
                                "error.message", new Object[]{},locale);  
            
            ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
            error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            error.setMessage(errorMessage);
        

            return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

// other Custom Exception handlers
```

Your ErrorResponse is normal javabean as below:

```
public class ErrorResponse{

private int errorCode;
private String message;

//getter and setter
}
```

And you should have MessageSource configured in your configuration to read the locale specific error messages as below:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest use of `@ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler`.

Also you can use @RestControllerAdvice, [find example here](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc/use-restcontrolleradvice-new-features-spring-framework-4-3)